# Rename a bunch of files in debian

Tags: regex, linux, debian, rename

I have thousands of files that I need to rename with the following format.
2008:09:18:17:45:48-alfanumeric-alfanumeric.wav the first part is a date.

Ex. **2008:09:18:17:45:48-703-s.wav**

A want to rename it to:

**20080918.174548.703.s.wav**

Basically to remove the ':' and to make a more human readable format and easier to split.

I know that rename is what im looking for but the regex is not working. I'm typing:

> rename
>   's/(\d):(\d):(\d):(\d):(\d):(\d)-(.?)-(.?).wav/$1$2$3.$4$5$6.$7.$8.wav/'
>   ./*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider multiplicities:

```
rename 's/(\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)-(.*)-(.?).wav/$1$2$3.$4$5$6.$7.$8.wav/' ./*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rename 's/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+).wav/$1$2$3.$4$5$6.$7.$8.wav/' ./*
```

should be used - in your version you always only match one digit. Plus, no need to escape the :.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you're only going to do once, I'd do it this way:

1) ls the files into a new file:  ls datadir > mytmp
2) edit the mytmp with your favorite editor.
  2a delete any lines that aren't data files you care about, like "." and ".."
  2b edit each line into a shell command to rename the file.  I like emacs, and 
     would build a keyboard macro to: clip the file name, insert "mv ", insert the 
     filename, insert space, insert the filename again, edit the inserted filename into 
     the desired format.
  2c save
3) run sh < mytmp

Done!  Not elegant, tedious if your editor doesn't support macros or similar functionality, but guaranteed to work and git-er-done.